# Creating a DLL for Windows Store 8.1 Apps

Tags: c#, .net, dll, windows-8.1

I'm attempting to create a DLL written in C# that will utilize Windows 8.1 packages such as `Windows.Storage` and `Windows.Media`. The DLL compiles using `csc.exe` when not including the classes that utilize the `Windows` packages.

When trying to compile the entire DLL (including the extra classes) I add the `/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd"` compiler option to include the missing Windows packages. The compiler then throws this error:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd: error CS0012: The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an
>           assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>           'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>           PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

However when I try to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll` the compiler gives `error CS0433` for nearly every class that I use stating that `The type '...' exists in both '...\mscorlib.dll' and '...\Runtime.dll'`.

Is there a way to only include the the necessary packages from the Runtime.dll? Or is there an entirely different way to easily compile this DLL?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't building this through Visual Studio?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Visual Studio refused to let me change the build settings to a library. So I write/test the code in Visual Studio but do the final builds via a batch file. I did eventually find a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/08a75933-1df9-4dc6-98a7-4bdc84ca1811/compiling-class-library-windows-store-apps-with-cscexe) for the curious by changing all the v4.5 directories to v4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, add a reference to the System.Runtime.dll facade. Typically, this facade is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`.

The underlying issue here is that different .NET implementations define the `System.Attribute` type on different assemblies. However, the .NET/Windows type projection layer– the glue that makes Windows Runtime types look like normal .NET types – and the compiler expect `System.Attribute` to be defined in System.Runtime.dll. This is true for some .NET implementations, but it isn't true for the in-box .NET Framework that comes with Windows.

The facade referenced above provides a pointer to the compiler that the implementation for `System.Attribute` is really in System.dll for this implementation.